# NSMakeRange crashing app

Tags: nsstring, substring

I'm trying to get a substring of a NSString using substringWithRange:NSMakeRange. I am getting the initial string from a saved dictionary, the saved string is written as agent_AGENTNAME, I'm trying to strip off the agent_ part. The code below works fine (feel free to critique it if it is crude) if I hard code the numbers in for the NSMakeRange - like so

```
NSString* savedAgentName =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [thisfile substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,19)]];
```

but since everyone will obviously have names of different lengths I need to make this more dynamic. When I switch the code to this:

```
 NSString* savedAgentName =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [thisfile substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,[thisfile length])]];
```

it crashes my app. Why?

Here's the larger chunk of code:

```
//get saved agents
 savedAgents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Select An Agent", nil];
 for(int f=0; f<[rootcontents count]; f++) {
      NSString* thisfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rootcontents objectAtIndex:f]];
      if ([thisfile rangeOfString:@"agent_"].location != NSNotFound) {

          int thisfilelength = [thisfile length];
          NSString* savedAgentName =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [thisfile substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,thisfilelength)]];
          //NSLog(@"%@", savedAgentName);

         [savedAgents addObject:savedAgentName];
      } 
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `substringWithRange:` method will (as the docs say) raise an NSRangeException "if any part of aRange lies beyond the end of the receiver".

By asking for thisfilelength characters starting from the 6th position in thisfile, you go past the end of the string resulting in an exception.

You need to reduce the length requested by 6 like this:

```
NSString *savedAgentName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
    [thisfile substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,thisfilelength-6)]];
```

By the way, this code could be simplified to:

```
NSString *savedAgentName = 
    [thisfile substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,thisfilelength-6)];
```

However, since you want the whole rest of the string from a certain index, this could be simplified even further by using `substringFromIndex:`:

```
NSString *savedAgentName = [thisfile substringFromIndex:6];
```

Note also that all the code above assumes the string has at least 6 characters.  To be safe, check that the length of thisfile is 6 or greater before getting the substring.  If it is less than 6 characters long, you can set savedAgentName to blank.

Comment: Hey, I didn't thank you for this answer but it has helped a lot. +1 for teaching me to fish!